# c# coding help needed

Tags: c#-4.0

My C# knowledge is limited and I'm having trouble getting this code to work. So I would really appreciate it if you guys can show me where I went wrong.

Code:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\C#Files\My Work\File.txt"));

string fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

reader.Close();

fileContent = fileContent.Replace("ccc","yyy");

StreamWriter writer =new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(@"C:\C#Files\My Work\File.txt"));

writer.Write(fileContent);

writer.Close();
```

These are the errors that I'm receiving:

> *FindandReplace.cs(1,1): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain
>           members such as fields or methods*
>
> *FindandReplace.cs(1,27): error CS1518: Expected class, delegate,
>   enum,
>           interface, or struct*
>
> *FindandReplace.cs(9,26): error CS1518: Expected class, delegate,
>   enum,
>           interface, or struct*

(If it helps, what I'm trying to do is to automate the Find&Replace function of most word processors by just having to run this program.)

Thanks.

Edit:

Yes I don't have and namespaces or anything else.

And this is the error that I now get:

C:\C#Files>csc FindandReplace.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

FindandReplace.cs(7,13): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or
        interface member declaration
FindandReplace.cs(9,13): error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or
        interface member declaration
FindandReplace.cs(9,34): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or
        interface member declaration
FindandReplace.cs(13,13): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or
        interface member declaration
FindandReplace.cs(13,25): error CS1519: Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or
        interface member declaration
FindandReplace.cs(15,13): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or
        interface member declaration

Comment: Uh did you not copy paste your namespace and class definitions, or do you really not have any? That might be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to define a class and/or a main-method, something like this:

```
namespace Whatever 
{

    public class Programm 
    {
        public static void main (string[] args)
        {
            // your code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though after doing what you said, I get this:

Answer (score 0):

You've put your code inside a `namespace` whereas it should be inside a `class`.

Try wrapping your code in the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void main (string [] args)
    {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Should be it

```
using System;
using System.IO; 

namespace test {
    class example {
        static void Main() {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\newlog.txt")); 
            string fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
            reader.Close(); 
            fileContent = fileContent.Replace("ccc", "yyy"); 
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(@"C:\log.txt")); 
            writer.Write(fileContent); 
            writer.Close(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Also, seeign your code looks like, better if you use the `static` method provided by `File` class

```
        File.ReadAllLines();
        File.WriteAllLines();
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst editing your code I noticed this:

```
StreamWriter writer =new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(@"C:\C#Files\My Work\File.txt"));
```

Notice the code error?

It should probably be:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(@"C:\C#Files\My Work\File.txt"));
```

There should be a whitespace after the assignment `=` operator